# Rails 3 Devise redirect within custom strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2, Devise 1.3.4

I implemented a custom Devise / Warden strategy to authenticate against a 3rd party API and if successful, a new user is created the first time. I should clarify that the user creation is done within the custom strategy code in `devise.rb`

```
devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.strategies.add(:mls_strategy) do
    def authenticate!
      ... authenticate against 3rd party API...
      if res.body =~ /success/
        u = User.find_or_initialize_by_email(params[:user][:email])
        if u.new_record?
          u.save
        end
      success!(u)
    end
  end
end
```

That all works except that that upon creation, the user sees the login page still with an alert saying `Signed in successfully`. The desired behavior is that the user gets redirected to the application's root which I tried to do by adding `redirect_to "/"` after creating user but it couldn't find `redirect_to` method and I'm not even sure that's the best way to do it.

I have also tried adding this to `routes.rb` without success

```
namespace :user do
  root :to => "blah#index"
end
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh, as it turns out, all I need to do is to use `save!` instead of just `save`. Apparently `save!` persists it to the database whereas `save` delays it causing Devise to not recognize the user as authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new controller "Registrations" and customize the appropriate method:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/an/example/path'
  end
end
```

you can find more information here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29

Comment: Tried it, it didn't even get invoked, so I suspect I have changed the flow of control in my custom strategy code. I think this needs to be done in the custom strategy code which is in `devise.rb`.